# How to share an LXC container between two compatible hosts?

Tags: lxc

I use Linux and I am in the process of migrating from one Linux Mint 15 into Linux Mint 16. Each OS is installed on the same partition as a different subvolume on the same btrfs partition.

As I use both systems at the moment, I'd like to share all LXC Containers across both distributions.

I deep-copied the whole `/var/lib/lxc/<container>` path to separate btrfs subvolume.

Surprisingly it is not as easy as it seems. Each time when I make any form of linking of the container source into /var/lib/lxc/ on the host, I got an error (`lxc-start: command get_init_pid failed to receive response`). Unfortunately, any form of delegation (symlinks, mount --bind) doesn't work.

Copying the container with `rsync -aAX` works well, but I don't want to maintain two separate instances of the container, but to share one instance between two host OSes.

Comment: It seems you try to link each container separately. If so, why do not you mount whole shared subvolume as /var/lib/lxc ?

Answer (score 1):

Try getting debug output from lxc:

```
   lxc-start -n container_name -o container.log -l DEBUG -d
```

there might be more information.

Also check lxc version, there's been quite huge progress in development lately, if you're running something like `lxc 1.0.0.alpha1` or earlier version you should consider upgrading.

Answer (score -2):

You should have a look at [Docker](http://docker.io) which encapsulates all of this for you and makes containers easily portable (besides many other awesome things).

Comment: I know it. But isn't it still at the beta phase? Maybe I'll give it a try anyway. Thank you.

Comment: I tried. I followed the simple docker "getting started" howto on Ubuntu, and the container keeps failing on the first command with `The container failed to start due to timed out.`. I guess they are indeed not really ready for production. (BTW it wasn't me who downvoted your answer)

Comment: This is a bug in old versions of the LXC utils shipped with Ubuntu. Make sure, your system is up-to-date, as the most recent version should have this bug fixed. Check also this Google Groups discussion regarding this: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/docker-user/n5uv5MzcPsY/2ds3L76sqlQJ

Comment: Yes, it seems I've became a victim of this bug. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski, it was me who upvoted your comment ;-P